# bash string matching table vs list of files

Tags: string, bash, loops, while-loop, match

I spent the last couple of hours on a simple script, but it is not working and I do not understand why.
I am working on a .txt table `/and_deduplicate.txt`:

```
ENCFF000VFN
ENCFF000VJE
ENCFF000VJG
ENCFF001ENH
ENCFF025MPI
ENCFF036NWL
ENCFF049OLR
ENCFF052BVG
```

and a list of files:

```
/ENCFF000VJE.bam    /ENCFF313EAL.bam
```

What I need is matching the name of the file with the code in the table.
I wrote this code:

```
 count=0;
 cat /and_deduplicate.txt | while read line ;do 
 let "count++"
 for filenames in /*.bam ;do
 filename2=${filenames##*/}             
 filename3=${filename2%.*}
 if [ "$line" = "$filename3" ] ;then
 echo "match"
 fi      
 done
 done
```

From my point of view, it seems right but I do not get the match as should occur with the label ENCFF000VJE
What am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: `"$filename3"`, not just `"filename3"`.

Comment: Do you need a solution of your task or you want to know mistakes in your script? If you need solution you may use <br> `for i in \`cat and_deduplicate.txt\` ; do if  [ -a $i.bam ] ; then echo $i ; fi ;  done`

Comment: Thank you I solved in this way:                                                                                        if [[ "$line" =~ $filename3 ]] ;then
        echo $count;    $count_1'